# Why cannot I print whats in the array token[ ] in this java program

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

The whole idea of the program is to read a file line by line and save each word into an array token[]. I am trying to print the elements in array token[] on to the console using for loop. But it says variable token has not been initialized.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] token;
        int i;

            try{
                // Open and read the file
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                String strLine;
                //Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
                while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                    token = strLine.split(" ");
                }   
                in.close();//Close the input stream
            }
            catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

                   // Why can't I do this printing part?
            for(i=0;i<=token.length;i++){
                System.out.println(token[i]);
            }``
        }// close main()
}// close Class
```

Comment: Suppose an exception is thrown when you open the file. You'll catch it, and continue... but `token` hasn't been set. Likewise if there's an empty file, it will never go into the body of your while loop. By the way, given that you're overwriting `token` on every iteration, you're actually only going to print the contents of the last line of the file...

Comment: Just a side note you don't need the DataInputStream here you can pass the fstream directly into the InputStreamReader.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 2):

When you're inside a method, such as main, variable declarations are not initialized, you must provide them with an initial value yourself.

eg:

String[] array = new String[0];

or even

String[] array = null;

Comment: A zero-length array won't print anything out.  That's *okay*.  A `null` array will cause a `NullPointerException` when attempting to iterate over it.  That's *not* okay.

Comment: No, that's the initialization value, the intent is to reassign it later...As this one receives its value in a try, the safe option is new String[0];

Answer (score 1):

The following Code:

```
    public class ReadFile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] token;
    int i;
    try{
        // Open and read the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        //Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            token = strLine.split(" ");
        }   
        in.close();//Close the input stream
    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

**should be changed to  this one:**

```
    public class ReadFile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] token = null;//initialize token with null
    int i;   
try{
        // Open and read the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));//Don't use DataInputStream as this class is good for reading primitives, length-prefixed strings e.t.c 
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String strLine;
        //Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            //token = strLine.split(" ");
            sBuilder.append(strLine);
        }   
        token = (sBuilder.toString()).split(" ");//Write this line here.
        in.close();//Close the input stream
    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Also change the for loop construct:

```
for(i=0;i<=token.length;i++){//This will give ArrayOutOfBoundException
        System.out.println(token[i]);
    }
```

To

```
if (token != null)
for(i=0; i<token.length; i++){// condition should be checked for i < token.length
        System.out.println(token[i]);
    }
```

**NOTE:** As suggested by  @Peter Lawrey [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) should be used especially for reading primitives.

Comment: Creating another String just to split it again seems quite wasteful, maybe use a instead of the array List to store the split tokens in each loop.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings: yeah I was thinking of the same too. But going by OP's line in question `save each word into an array token[]` I choosed to keep `split` method for getting words instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: This still will break it into list of arrays. What OP is looking for is entire words stored in an array.

Comment: Well then use my first approach use one List and then use toArray() at the end.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings: Then there you are doing whole operations in two parts. In first part you are splitting the line in words and adding them to `ArrayList` and in second part you are converting the `ArrayList` int `array` of strings  usint `list.toArray()`.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of scope.

In the scope of `main()`. `token` is defined but not initialized.  If you want to use `token` at this scope level, you have to initialize it.

In the scope of the try...catch block, `token` is initialized.  Curiously, its value will only matter for the last line, as `split()` creates a new `String[]` every time through, and you're reassigning it to `token`.

Answer (score 0):

check this code, you will understand where the problem is.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ReadFile{
public static void main(String args[]){
ArrayList<String[]> tokenlist = new ArrayList<>();
int i;

try{
    // Open and read the file
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("health.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    //Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
    while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
         String[] token = strLine.split(" ");
        tokenlist.add(token);
    }   
    //in.close();//Close the input stream
}
catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}

       // Why can't I do this printing part?
for(int count=0; count<tokenlist.size();count++){
    String[] token = tokenlist.get(count);
    for(i=0;i<token.length;i++){
        System.out.println(token[i]);
    }
 }

 }// close main()
 }
```

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.